# How to get all admins of multisite in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, customization, multisite

**How to get all admins of multisite in wordpress.**
 I am create custom plugin for  this
I am stuck in custom code for get all the  admins of multisite in main website.
for ex. my main website is : wyz.com and my second site is : xyz.com/demo.
main website admin is "abc" and for " xyz.com/demo" site admin is "abcde".
Now how i get "abcde" admin in my main website .

In my live site i have currently  6k admins. So i difficult to get this . I am new in multisite wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from any of the sub site, you first need to switch to that site using [switch_to_blog()](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) function. Then whatever the query you fire, it will give records from that site only. Don't forget to restore it to current site, once you get the data from sub-site. You can restore it using [restore_current_blog()](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog) function.

To get the all admin users of all the sites, you need to perform the followings:

1) Use [wp_get_sites()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sites/) function to get the blog_id of all the sites.

2) Once you get the blog_id, You need to perform the following loop to get the admin user of each the sites.

Assume that you get `$blog` as array of `blog_ids` from `wp_get_sites()` function

```
foreach ($blogs as $blog) 
    {
        switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id ); // blog id which u got from wp_get_sites() function
        $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
                    'role' => 'administrator', 
                    'orderby' => 'display_name'
                    ) );  // query to get admin users
        $results = $users_query->get_results();
        $site_admins .= 'Blog ID: ' . $blog->blog_id . '<pre>' . print_r($results,true) . '</pre>';
    }
    restore_current_blog();
```