# search user by phone number in wc-users and wc-orders when creating new order on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a lot of customers who text us to place an order and I want to be able to search the user by phone number in 2 locations so that I can retrieve the user and place their order. The 2 locations I need this search functionality is:

1. On the wc-orders "new order" page (wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-orders&action=new)
2. On the wc-users page (wp-admin/users.php)

[image]

I have tried using a plugin however the plugin seems outdated and did not work: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/better-user-search/

I have tried using the code here: [How to search customer by billing phone In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030774/how-to-search-customer-by-billing-phone-in-woocommerce)

But once I add this code as a php snippet using a php snippet code plugin I get a critical error when searching for the user by phonenumber.

Error when searching user by phonenumber on the users.php page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from [your reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030774/how-to-search-customer-by-billing-phone-in-woocommerce) will not work as a `.php` snippet. `searchform.php` has been customized for use native searcher.

Actually you don't have to modify any core files in order to be able to search for customers by billing_phone. You can just use the `woocommerce_customer_search_customers` filter-hook.

**To be able to search for users by phone number, in the search functionality, when creating new order, you can use this code:**

```
/* Search customers or users by phone number, when creating new orders */

add_filter ('woocommerce_customer_search_customers', 'custom_add_billing_phone_to_search_function', 10, 4);
function custom_add_billing_phone_to_search_function ($filter, $term, $limit, $type){ 
  if ($type == 'meta_query'){ 
    $filter['meta_query'][] = array(
      'key' => 'billing_phone',
      'value' => $term, 
      'compare' => 'LIKE' ); 
  } return $filter; 
}
```

[For more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085106/wc-how-can-i-search-customer-by-billing-phone-or-billing-email)

**To modify the user search for Wordpress admin to include billing phone then return the results to the user table**

I found one way to achieve this by using the `pre_user_query` to modify the wp_query. This link is also the [source of the code below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215337/10497022). I just modified it to contain only billing_phone.

However, you should know that the below code is very search sensitive.
It will only find the user by billing_phone, depending on how the phone number is saved/stored/formatted and how you actually search for it.

**Example:**
If the phone number is saved as one combined number (123456789). Then you would need to search for the combined number, or parts of the combination, as combined numbers (456 or 789). As soon as you add a spacing between a number (123 456789) you will not get results if you search for the combined number (123456789).

So make sure that the user billing_phone has same format as the phone number you are searching for. You can always edit a user phone number and format it to your liking.

For further reference on `pre_user_query`, you can [read this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/).

```
/* Allow to search for customer by phone number on the user page */
add_action( 'pre_user_query', function( $uqi ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = '';
    if ( isset( $uqi->query_vars['search'] ) )
        $search = trim( $uqi->query_vars['search'] );

    if ( $search ) {
        $search = trim($search, '*');
        $the_search = '%'.$search.'%';

        $search_meta = $wpdb->prepare("
        ID IN ( SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta}
        WHERE ( ( meta_key='billing_phone' )
            AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value LIKE '%s' )
        )", $the_search);

        $uqi->query_where = str_replace(
            'WHERE 1=1 AND (',
            "WHERE 1=1 AND (" . $search_meta . " OR ",
            $uqi->query_where );
    }
});
```

To be added at the bottom in your functions.php file, or the plguin you use.

Comment: Thank you this worked wonderfully for searching by billing_phone when making a new order. Is there a way to search customers by phone number in the wp-users.php as well?

Comment: @javitoor1001 I edited my answer to also include how to search for customers in the user panel for admin. Just be aware of how you format the phone numbers vs. how you search for the phone number. To keep it simple, try and use the same format.

Comment: Hey Richard, I added the second snippet and it didnt do anything. I forgot to mention I have a multisite setup. Can this have something to do with the code not working?

Comment: @javitoor1001 If it has to do with mutlisite, when WP get’s users it only gets them from the current blog. To get the data from any of the sub site, you first need to switch to that site using `switch_to_blog()` function. Then you would use `get_sites()` function to get the blog_id of all the sites and perform a loop to get phone number of users from all sites, a bit like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015681/10497022). I would advice to make a new question with focus on multisite. Example "How to search for users by phone number in wordpress multisite". Reference to this post